# Why does my div overlap other divs on the bottom?

Tags: html, css

The  class circle displays in the area that belongs to  abslute. I thought it should appear below it, not overlapping it. When I put it on top, it displays ok (well, on top). Why doesn't it display right on the bottom?

```css
.gen {
  font-size: 60px;
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
}

.relative {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  font-family: 'Ma Shan Zheng', cursive;
  font-size: 13vw;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}

.abslute {
  background-color: rgb(32, 185, 231);
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 13vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

h1 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.circle {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(241, 13, 13, 0.767);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ma+Shan+Zheng&display=swap");
</style>

<body>
  <div class="circle">circle</div>
  <div class="gen">
    <div class="relative">Words relative</div>
    <div class="abslute">Other absolute</div>
  </div>
  <div class="circle">circle</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Note: the `<meta>` tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in HTML. (Not a fix for anything.)

Comment: probably because : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#absolute  : **absolute** -:-
    *The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned relative to its closest positioned ancestor, if any; otherwise, it is placed relative to the initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.*.

Answer (score 1):

Your `.gen` class is restricting the view height so your circle overlaps. I've extended the view width in the code snippet below so you can see the difference.

Removing the `.gen` class entirely also works.

```css
.gen {
  font-size: 60px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
}

.relative {
  background-color: darksalmon;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vw;
  font-family: 'Ma Shan Zheng', cursive;
  font-size: 13vw;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin: 3px;
}

.abslute {
  background-color: rgb(32, 185, 231);
  height: 70%;
  width: 70%;
  font-size: 13vw;
  border: 3px solid black;
}

h1 {
  border: 3px solid black;
  background-color: burlywood;
  width: 35%;
  height: 35%;
  font-size: 10vw;
}

.circle {
  border: 3px solid black;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(241, 13, 13, 0.767);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ma+Shan+Zheng&display=swap");
</style>

<body>
  <div class="circle">circle</div>
  <div class="gen">
    <div class="relative">Words relative</div>
    <div class="abslute">Other absolute</div>
   </div>
   <div class="circle">circle</div>
 

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @GhastlyCode, I am amazed by StackOverflow. :)
Just one thing to clarify, if we change the values in the .gen class... it will affect the "abslute" class as there I specified the size in %, and as it is a child of the .gen it will change its size. How about changing the .gen dimentions to min-height value? Do you think it is also a good way to solve this problem? It just worked for me.

Comment: that would also work, min-height stands for Minimum height. So if you set minimum height to 200vw then it'll never be smaller but can always increase in size if needed. This is why it stops overlapping. :)